# GCM: cannot send message from python script

Tags: python, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

I'm following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-server-to-send-push-notifications-with-gcm-to-android-devices-using-python) tutorial to send GCM message from a server via a python script.

I've downloaded the [GcmDemo](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/) that can successfully send messages to itself using my *project num*, *server API key* and *reg id*.

But no way to do it from python.

I've registered the client:

```
06-13 09:47:45.682   2272-32480/com.google.android.gcm.demo I/GcmDemo﹕ registration succeeded.
    senderId: 11xxxxxxx07
    token: fxq...xxxx..r5
```

My server API key:

[image]

The python script on the server:

```
from gcm import *
gcm = GCM("AIza...xxx...XQ")
data = {'ciao ciao': 'test message', 'param2': 'value2'}
reg_id = 'fxq...xxxx..r5'
gcm.plaintext_request(registration_id=reg_id, data=data)
```

No error messages but no messages received.

Is there a way to log and see where the problem is ?

The client doesn't react (log on Android Studio set to verbose, no log at all).

Any idea ?

The google project console just shows logs till 30 May.

Comment: Look at the response error thrown by the script. For example, `response = gcm.json_request(...)`.

Comment: Error handling can be seen under [this section](https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm#usage).

Comment: Thanks but I solved using php without python. I'm quite sure that it doesn't work due to missing data fields like `icon` (that is mandatory). It was not working also via php, then I added `icon` to *data* and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Python anymore as I switched to PHP but I had the same problem there and solved adding the `icon` field to the "*data*". So adding something like:

```
data = {'icon' : '@drawable/myAwesomeIcon', ...}
```

should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was not working when i put dry_Run =True, but worked on removing drun_Run.dry_Run=True was giving me fake_message_id.